# Exponential function

Tags: equations

I have a problem creating an exponential function in equation mode in Latex. I would like to have this exponential function: exponential^((y^2)/4). Does anyone know have to do that?
David

Comment: Try $e^{y^2/4}$

Comment: the first `^` has base `l` and exponent `(` and the second `^` has base `/` and exponent `2`  I would guess that is not what you intend, but I can not guess what function you did intend

Comment: When not in \begin{equation} mode $e^{y^2/4}$ works fine, but it does not work in \begin{equation} mode.

Comment: As you were told on the previous question `$` is for starting math mode, so you should not use it if you are already in math mode in `equation`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the `equation` environment, you shouldn't use the `$` sign(*):

```
\begin{equation} e^{y^2/4} \end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{equation} e^{\frac{1}{4} y^2} \end{equation}
```

should work.

(*) Except in such cases:

```
\begin{equation} x=0 \text{ if $x$ and $y$ are nice people} \end{equation}
```

Comment: the euler e should be upright, so `\mathrm{e}` or `\exp(...)`

Comment: e is a constant, therefore it should be upright.

Comment: @MaxNoe Upright e is a convention used in certain fields, but certainly not all.  As pure mathematician I don't set it upright.  Nor would I use `\operatorname{e}`,  however I do use `\exp(...)` inline and on large expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In my case, I think all the e-expressions you gave me works perfectly well. Thanks!

Comment: @MaxNoe why do you say so? All constants should be upright? For example, wikipedia does not use that convention for the exponential function page.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{equation}
e^{\frac{y^2}{4}}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: This is already covered in the existing answer.